# Openxml - How to convert HTML with styles?

Tags: c#, html, xml, ms-word, openxml

I am trying to create Word document by using Openxml and got a problem when Openxml doesn't understand Html tags in a way I needed it.

In my test project (to see how it works at all) I have done second thing:

```
using (var package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filename, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
     package.AddMainDocumentPart();

     var mainPart = package.MainDocumentPart;
     mainPart.Document = new Document();
     var body = new Body();

     var sectionProp = new SectionProperties();
     var pageSetup = new PageMargin() { Top = 1701, Left= 1134, Right = 1134, Bottom = 850 };
     sectionProp.Append(pageSetup);

     body.Append(sectionProp);

     var converter = new HtmlConverter(mainPart);

     var para = converter.Parse(@"<b>Testing Html</b><b>Testing Html2</b>");

     var runProp = new RunProperties();
     runProp.Append(new Bold(), new FontSize() {Val = "32"});

     var paragProp = new ParagraphProperties();
     var justif = new Justification() {Val = JustificationValues.Center};
     paragProp.Append(justif);

     body.Append(new Paragraph(paragProp, new Run(runProp, new Text("<b>Testing</b>"))), para[0]);    
     mainPart.Document.Append(body);
}

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
```

I get it that Html2Openxml converts Html text to a bunch of paragraphs, **but that the problem for me**, because I also need to **add some styles to it**.

Do I need to send some styles with html (how i supposed to do that, just style="" everywhere or it can understand css to some extend?) to it to convert properly, or is there a way to somehow give to converted paragraph styles?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Word does not handle linked Stylesheets, such as . And, I even had to find them and remove them with a good RegularExpress because those tags still had some negative visual affects within the Word Document.

When exporting to Word, I use HttpWebRequest to run my stylesheets, and stream their Response to a StringBuilder, all of the content placed within a style tag, and then I use string.Replace to replace some placeholder text on my markup (that placeholder text only shows when I am in Print to Word mode). Below, "pageSource" is the OnRender event's HtmlTextWriter text that I grab instead of going out to the browser (then I go from there to manipulate the HTML with string.Replace and Regex.Replace, etc). You may or may not need the CookieContainer and cookie foreach loop, depending on your site security (tokens) and other use of cookies.

```
    public string PutOurStylesInBlockForWordExport(string pageSource, string webRoot)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(@"<style type=""text/css"">");

        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(webRoot + "Styles/reset.css") as HttpWebRequest;
        HttpWebRequest req2 = WebRequest.Create(webRoot + "Styles/style.css") as HttpWebRequest;
        CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
        req.CookieContainer = cc;
        req2.CookieContainer = cc;
        var cookies = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies;
        foreach (string key in cookies.AllKeys)
        {
            Cookie c = new Cookie(cookies[key].Name, cookies[key].Value);
            Uri root = new Uri(webRoot);
            req.CookieContainer.Add(root, c);
            req2.CookieContainer.Add(root, c);
        }

        System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            sb.Append(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());
        }

        System.Net.WebResponse resp2 = req2.GetResponse();
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp2.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            sb.Append(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());
        }

        sb.AppendLine(@"</style>");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```